# In C#, when I make my mainForm a MDIContainer, it adds a border... How do I remove it?

Tags: c#, mdi, mdiparent

Here's a link displaying the issue: http://imageshack.us/f/844/pa82.png/

Basically, I've created a form that is full screen, set that form to a MDIContainer so that I can add other forms inside of it, and also remove them.

As soon as I set the MDIContainer the form's appearance started giving me issues, such as it changed the background color to gray and added that border. I've fixed the background color by changing the MDIClient background color (found via a foreach statement, shown below), but I can't find any border settings...

```
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            MdiClient client = control as MdiClient;
            if (!(client == null))
            {
                client.BackColor = Color.Black;

                break;
            }
        }
```

Any idea what that thing is, and how I can remove/hide it?

Comment: That's not possible, the MDI model dictates the border style.

Comment: So What you're saying, Hans Passant, is that I'm 100% stuck with that ugly border?

Comment: MDI dates from the early 1990s, ugly is by design.  It makes very little sense on modern machines anymore, you don't have a 640 x 480 monitor anymore.

Comment: A quick search gave me this link: [How to remove 3D border from MDIClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752696/how-to-remove-3d-border-sunken-from-mdiclient-component-in-mdi-parent-form) (untested though)

Comment: Just don't use MDI!...instead of setting MdiParent for "children", set their TopLevel() property to false and this will allow you to add those child forms to the "parent" just like any other control.  *Turn off IsMdiContainer for "parent" form too*.